# How to hide a section, while keeping the numbering and references intact?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, pdf

I'm writing a paper consisting of several long sections. Each section contains labeled items that are sometimes referenced in other sections. My method of writing is linear: I write one section until I'm satisfies with it, and then I move on to write the next section. I'd like to be able to print to pdf only the current section, but keep the references and the section numbers intact as when the entire document is printed.

Comment: You could `\include` each section and use `\includeonly`.

Comment: @TeXnician: Thanks. Could you please give me a usage example?

Comment: @TeXnician: `\include` has the 'issue' of shipping a clearpage first... if that is not a problem, the idea is the same I had ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: And if it is a problem?

Comment: Patch `\@include`. Although I do not know if that is a good idea, because of the aux files which are written.

Comment: @EvanAad: It is no problem if you accept possibly empty pages between your sections...

Comment: @TeXnician: Possibly the asynchronous writing of content to the `.aux` file could be a problem by patching `\include` (kicking out `\clearpage` etc.). I have to check, but I am short of time right now